# Rewriting using sigma notation

Tags: summation, fractions

I need help rewriting in sigma notation. The index beginning starts with 1 and ends with 7. I can't figure out the formula to use. Thanks.

$$\dfrac{25}4 - \dfrac52 + 1 - \dfrac 25 + \dfrac 4{25} - \dfrac 8{125} + \dfrac{16}{625}$$

Comment: This is a [geometric progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression). Can you identify what the common ratio between any two consecutive terms is?

Comment: **HINT**: All the terms are powers of $5/2$ or of $2/5$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

The first term is $\left(-\dfrac25\right)^{-2},$ and the last is $\left(-\dfrac25\right)^{4}.$

(I used a negative sign to get the terms alternating in sign.)

Comment: Thanks J.W I appreciate your hint!

Comment: This is the sum formula I got: ![formula] [1] 

[1] : https://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5E%7B7%7D%5Cleft%20%28%20-%5Cfrac%7B2%7D%7B5%7D%20%5Cright%20%29%5E%7Bk-3%7D